# libcurl/C : when can I free header and postdata buffers?

Tags: c, libcurl

In https://curl.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html there is a basic example of how to have libcurl set custom headers. But in the case **when the header string is an allocated char array**, it is unclear to me when to free it. I would prefer libcurl to duplicate my header strings so I can free them immediately after setting the header (and not after the perform() or cleanup()).

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
char *header = malloc(50);
strcpy(header, "my-header: ABC");
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, myheader);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
...
curl_easy_perform(curl);
// I would prefer to free here
// because I can run this curl handle with new headers
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
// shall I free here or will it be free by above call?
```

I have the same question for POSTdata:

```
char *postdata = strdup("a=1&b=2");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(postdata));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postdata);
// can I free postdata here? << preferred
curl_easy_perform(curl);
// can I free here?
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
// must I free here?
```

I would prefer to have libcurl duplicate `postdata` so I can free it at my own time and then libcurl can free its copy when it is done with it.

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [curl_easy_setopt](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) states:

> Strings passed to libcurl as 'char *' arguments, are copied by the library; thus the string storage associated to the pointer argument may be overwritten after curl_easy_setopt returns.

Regarding CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS it reads:

> The only exception to this rule is really CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but the alternative that copies the string CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS has some usage characteristics you need to read up on.

So if you want libcurl to duplicate postdata you would need to use the
[CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) instead.

There it reads:

> Pass a char * as parameter, which should be the full data to post in a HTTP POST operation. It behaves as the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option, but the original data is instead copied by the library, allowing the application to overwrite the original data after setting this option.